# Eclipse Git and command-line git discrepency

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, gitignore

In Eclipse which has EGit installed, I find three files with file names starting with `.#` that needs to be committed (actually more accurately it's their removal needs to be committed).  Whereas in command-line `git status` I find no local uncommitted modification.  My `.gitignore` does NOT have a line

```
syntax: glob
.\#*
```

.

I added the above ignore pattern but see no change of the above described scenario.

Comment: In command-line, what does return a `git check-ignore -v -- path/to/your/.#file`?

Comment: It returns nothing, i.e. the second line on the command-line is empty.

Comment: Ok, so it isn't ignored at all. And a `git add -A` doesn't show those files as being deleted?

Comment: Running `git add -A` prints out nothing.

Comment: Is it possible that Eclipse consider a repo at a different path than the one you are considering in command line?

Comment: I just checked that they are same path.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a `.gitattributes` in that repo which declares a `smudge` script?

Comment: I only have `.git` and `.gitignore` (files/folders with name starting with `.git`) in that repo folder.